# Import npm JS Module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, electron

I would like to use [electron-settings](http://github.com/nathanbuchar/electron-settings) inside my Electron App based on the Angular 5 Framework. 
However, I am not able to import it into a TypeScript file.

```
import { Settings } from 'electron-settings';
```

The Error Message: The Module electron-settings does not contain the Member "Settings".

Is there a easy way, for a beginner like me, to use this Module inside TypeScript?

Also I´ve found [typed-electron-settings](http://github.com/legion44/typed-electron-settings) which may help, but since the Description on how to use it is pretty small, I dont know how to do so.

EDIT:

By using `import * as settings from 'electron-settings';` I get the following Error Message at `mySettings: settings;`

"The Name settings was not found"

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as settings from 'electron-settings';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

mySettings: settings;

constructor() {

}

// ...
```

Comment: `import * as settings from "electron-settings"` - it's not a named export, so you're using the incorrect syntax.

Comment: Results in "The Name settings was not found"